# Customize a class and change it dynamically when needed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, class

I have a simple class that's defined like :

```
public class SomeDataObject
{
    public int LabelId { get; set; }        
    public string LabelDesc { get; set; }               
    public double FirstValue { get; set; } 
}
```

Is it possible to add properties to the class when I choose to ?

For example :

```
public double SecondValue { get; set; }
```

Comment: Have a look at `ExpandoObject`, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx ... "Represents an object whose members can be dynamically added and removed at run time"

Answer (score 2):

If your `SomeDataObject` derives from `ExpandoObject`, you can extend the object without the need to create the properties.

So with this:

```
public class SomeDataObject : ExpandoObject { }
```

... this is valid:

```
SomeDataObject s = new SomeDataObject();
s.SecondValue = 123d;
```

If you don't know the name at compile time, you can set it like it is a dictionary (which it actually is):

```
d["SecondValue"] = 123d;
```

Comment: As an alternative, you could add a field ``public ExpandoObject Extra { get; set; }`` in order to have a well-defined fundament but an option to expand if needed.

Comment: @ron: need more help?